# how to call methods defined in module inside a class in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datagrid, devise, module

My code:

I have used `AuthenticationRelated` only in the `ApplicationHelper`
also `signed_in?` in `is_admin?` is from Devise Gem.

```
module AuthenticationRelated
 def is_admin?
    athu = false
    if signed_in?
      current_user.roles.each do |role|
        if role.name == 'admin'
          athu = true
        end
      end
    end
    athu
  end
end
```

Now I have a class `SalesReportsGrid` which I need to be able to access the `is_admin?` 
So this is what I have done:

```
class SalesReportsGrid

  include Datagrid
  include AuthenticationRelated

  scope do
    if is_admin?
      Sales.joins(product: [ category: [:access_lists] ] )
    else
     ....
    end
  end
....
end
```

Now when I run this I get the following error:

```
undefined method `is_admin?` for SalesReportsGrid:Class
```

**Edit**

When I add `extend AuthenticationRelated`

This is what I get:

```
undefined method `signed_in?` for SalesReportsGrid:Class
```

I am really confused, can someone please have a look and suggest something?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you `include` module, you add its methods to instances of the class where you used `include`. To make module methods 'class methods' (i.e. singleton methods of class), you should use `extend`:

```
extend AuthenticationRelated
```

Comment: When I add `extend AuthenticationRelated` I will get this error `undefined method signed_in? for SalesReportsGrid:Class`. `signed_in?` method is defined in Devise Gem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be explicit in using `current_user` to define grid scope.

Here is example:

```
def index
  @grid = SalesReportGrid.new(params[:sales_report_grid]) do |scope|
    unless current_user.admin?
      scope.where_accessible_by(current_user)
    end
  end
end
```

It allows you to be more explicit and don't move access control to the grid and leave it in controller like it use to happen in other places.